# Swift 3 - override initializer for UINavigationController to set rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, initialization, overriding

I'm using Swift 3 to override an init method that initializes my Navigation Controller with a rootviewcontroller (and set the rootviewcontroller delegate to self).  But, I'm getting the following error:

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'rootViewController:', expected
>   'coder:')

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController, RootViewControllerDelegate {

    let rvc = RootViewController()

    convenience init() {
        self.init(rootViewController: rvc) // Incorrect argument label in call (have 'rootViewController:', expected 'coder:')
        self.rvc.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong please?  I initially tried using

> override func init()

but Xcode ultimately had me convert that to

> convenience init()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `init(rootViewController:)` is defined in `UINavigationController`, which is the super class of your `NavigationController` class. Therefore, you should use `super` instead of `self` to refer to it:

```
init() {
    super.init(rootViewController: rvc)
    self.rvc.delegate = self
}
```

Since you have one other initializer defined in `NavigationController`, Xcode thinks that you were trying to call *that* initializer. That's why it tells you to put `coder:` as the argument label.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation, Sweeper.  When I use your solution, the error becomes: Convenience initializer for 'NavigationController' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init').  Thoughts?

Comment: @Vee Just remove `convenience`